# What is the better and faster way to save and get files Azure BLOB storage or SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql-server, wcf, azure, storage

[Background]
Now I am creating WCF for keeping and getting articles of our university.

I need to save files and metadata of these files.
My WCF need to be used by 1000 person a day.
The storage will contains about 60000 aticles.

I have three different ways to do it.

1. I can save metadata(file name, file type) in sql server to create unique id) and save files into Azure BLOB storage.
2. I can save metadata and data into sql server.
3. I can save metadata and data into Azure BLOB storage.

What way do chose and why ?
If you suggest your own solution, it will be wondefull.
P.S. Both of them use Azure.

Comment: What are you going to do with the files? Will your users be able to download these files?

Comment: @Gaurav Mantri they can download, send(create) files , update(remove and send again), remove.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend going with option 1 - save metadata in database but save files in blob storage. Here're my reasons:

1. Blob storage is meant for this purpose only. As of today an account can hold 500TB of data and size of each blob can be of 200 GB. So space is not a limitation.
2. Compared to SQL Server, it is extremely cheap to store in blob storage.
3. The reason I am recommending storing metadata in database is because blob storage is a simple object store without any querying capabilities. So if you want to search for files, you can query your database to find the files and then return the file URLs to your users.

However please keep in mind that because these (database server and blob storage) are two distinct data stores, you won't be able to achieve transactional consistency. When creating files, I would recommend uploading files in blob storage first and then create a record in the database. Likewise when deleting files, I would recommend deleting the record from the database first and then removing blob. If you're concerned about having orphaned blobs (i.e. blobs without a matching record in the database), I would recommend running a background task which finds the orphaned blobs and delete them.